# Can a textarea be sized to the content entered into it

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea on a form that is populated with text from a database query ready for someone to edit.

I would like the textarea to show the whole content without the need to scroll, but don't want to put a large textarea when there is only a small amount of text.

Text can be from 5 to 300 characters.

I have seen a solution to this type of issue but only where the textarea grows onkeyup as shown below.

```
<script>
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
o.style.height = "1px";
o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
</script>
<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `onkeyup`. It's not suitable for detecting text input.

I use the following code to resize a textarea to constantly resize a `textarea` element to fit the content:

```
var tarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

tarea.oninput = function () {
    tarea.style.height = tarea.scrollHeight + "px";
}
​
```

However, `oninput` isn't supported in older versions of IE, so you'll need to add `onpropertychange` if you need it to work in IE 8 and lower:

```
var tarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

tarea.oninput = tarea.onpropertychange = function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.evt;
    if (evt.type == "propertychange" && evt.propertyName != "value")
        return;

    tarea.style.height = tarea.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D5e8t/**

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for that. Your code works fine execpt the textarea is being populated when the page load from database content. So i need to type in the box to trigger your script. I want the textarea to size to the text being added there when the page is being built.

Comment: @DarrenCook: in that case, just call the same code `tarea.style.height = tarea.scrollHeight + "px"` when the document is loaded (ie, in a separate script included at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the content of textarea to a invisible div, with the same width, and styles that affect size (font-size, line-height, padding, etc.). Measure the height of said div, and set your textarea to the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Just little modifications to the above code will make textarea autosizable. 
Just perfiorm the below steps

1) Add id to your text area

`<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" id="txt" runat="server" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>`

2) Before a closing of bode tag add the javascript code to call the testAreaAdjust block

`<script type="text/javascript">`
`textAreaAdjust(document.getElementById('txt'));`
`</script>`

This will autosize the textbox.
Hope this will help you